# PHP hashing function that returns an integer (32bit int)

Tags: php, mysql, hash, integer

The goal is to store the hash on a mysql database, using INT (not BIGINT or MEDIUMINT). 
`md5('string', true)` returns binary data, 16 bytes of hash. I thought i could grep the first 4 bytes and convert it to an INT(32bit/4bytes) integer, but i don't know how to do it.

What do you suggest? Thanks.

Comment: `$int = bindec(substr(md5('string', true),0,4))` or `$int = hexdec(substr(md5('string'),0,8))` - but, fairly obviously, this does not store the whole hash, only the first 4 bytes of it.

Comment: May I ask, what is going to be such a "hash" purpose?

Comment: @DaveRandom: `bindec` won't work (`hexdec` does).

Comment: @hakre indeed it does not work - why is that?

Comment: @cedivad: Is the INT in your MySQL signed or unsigned?

Comment: @DaveRandom: bin is binary is 0000111100010101 and the like, not binary as char = 1 byte.

Comment: @hakre ahhh right I see. Is there no function in PHP that converts the literal binary representation of a string to a number? I though that's what `bindec()` did (although I have never used it/needed to do it and  now I read the manual properly I find that I was incorrect)

Comment: i will adjust my mysql field to signed/unsigned basing on what i will need... Thanks Dave, i will go that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ord($hash[0]) * 16777216 + ord($hash[1]) * 65536 + ord($hash[2]) * 256 + ord($hash[3]) ;
```

Or:

```
unpack("L", substr($hash,0,4));
```

But Filip Roséen's solution is better.

Answer (score 29):

Use [`crc32`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crc32.php), it will return a 32bit `int`.

---

```
var_dump (crc32 ("hello world"));
var_dump (crc32 ("world hello"));
```

output

```
int(222957957)
int(1292159901)
```

---

### [PHP: crc32 - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crc32.php)

> Generates the cyclic redundancy checksum polynomial of 32-bit lengths
>   of the str. This is usually used to validate the integrity of data
>   being transmitted.
>
> Because PHP's integer type is signed, and many crc32 checksums will
>   result in negative integers, you need to use the "%u" formatter of
>   sprintf() or printf() to get the string representation of the unsigned
>   crc32 checksum.

Answer (score 7):

The php `hash()` function will be even better than `crc32()`:

```
hash("crc32b", $str);
```

And if an integer is required:

```
intval(hash("crc32b", $str), 16);
```

Compared to the plain `crc32()`, it will not be affected by the signed/unsigned integer inconsistency between 32-bit and 64-bit systems (see PHP docs for the details: [crc32](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crc32.php))

Answer (score 2):

Here is Daniel J. Bernstein hash that returns an 32bit integer.

```
function djb_hash($str) {
  for ($i = 0, $h = 5381, $len = strlen($str); $i < $len; $i++) {
    $h = (($h << 5) + $h + ord($str[$i])) & 0x7FFFFFFF;
  }
  return $h;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use a map to link your hash to integer, such as Redis.

L43F34FLK34FL3K4 ==> 1

LKZLCKCLK32 ==> 2

etc....

Comment: You mean like a DB table where we store the hash + an auto-increment value? Or do you have a solution in mind, where we can compute the integer value dynamically?